# Missing repository problem (404 Not Found)

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, repository, mate-desktop

My system spec is:

```
Release 15 (olivia)    
Kernel Linux 3.8.0-19-generic   
MATE 1.6.0
```

I have recently been unable to install or upgrade any new package. I am getting many errors like this:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main
libcairo-script-interpreter2 amd64 1.12.14-0ubuntu1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

I also added the following line to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, but it didn't help either (the following line is the only line in that file):

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

How can I solve the problem?

p.s.
The content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d dir:

> local-repository.list
>   nvbn-rm-ppa-raring.list
>   official-package-repositories.list
>   plexydesk-plexydesk-dailybuild-raring.list

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: @chaos Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this response in the Linux Mint forums:

The reason for having these errors is that Mint 15 "Olivia" is no longer supported since January 2014. Mint 15 is obsolete and no longer supported. You need to either upgrade to Mint 17 if your system is not too old or install Mint 13. Both versions are LTS versions which stands for Long Term Support:

- Linux Mint 13 "Maya" => support ends in April 2017
- Linux Mint 17 "Qiana" => support ends in April 2019

For both versions all 4 desktop environments are available:

- Cinnamon
- Mate
- Xfce
- KDE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other sources? Either edit your `sources.list` and set another source (other than Ubuntu) or change it from your software GUI.